# How to update the helm release through terraform

Tags: terraform, helm3, infrastructure, terraform-provider-helm

```
helm ls
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                 STATUS  CHART       APP VERSION
portworx    default     1       2022-08-25 06:01:24.991655337 +0000 UTC deployed
```

Can someone help me in updating the above helm resources using terraform ?

```
resource "helm_release" "portworx" {
  chart         = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/community/"
  name          = "portworx"
  reuse_values  = true
  dependency_update= true
  force_update  = true
  recreate_pods = false
  wait          = true
  max_history   = 1
}
```

I have written above code but instead of updating the chart it is trying to create again. Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: What version of the chart are you using and to which version you want to update it to?

Comment: Currently I am using v2.9.0 and trying to update it to v2.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, that should be fairly easy to do, just use `version` argument [1] in the `helm_resource`:

```
resource "helm_release" "portworx" {
  chart             = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/community/"
  name              = "portworx"
  reuse_values      = true
  dependency_update = true
  force_update      = true
  recreate_pods     = false
  wait              = true
  max_history       = 1
  version           = "2.9.1"
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#version

Comment: Can you please explain what is the importance of dependency_update parameter here ?

Comment: Well, I just copied it over from your question and added the `version` field.

Comment: Can we divide this code into modules and call from resources from other folder ?

Comment: You can modularize almost anything in terraform, so I would say yes.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question with as many detalis as possible.

Comment: Can't be do this update without version variable so that it pick the latest version

Comment: When `version` is not specified, the chart will install the latest version: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#version. However, it depends on when you installed it the first time as from then on there can be updates so that version you have installed locally is no longer the latest.

Comment: But it is not getting updated to latest

Comment: When I tried without version and it ran the upgrade but I don't see any changes in helm chart version

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work -- at least not with the provider versions 2.6 through 2.7. What version did it work on? (Some resources are updated, not all, especially not charts found in requiremenst.yaml).

Comment: Dang. I'm wrong. And I can't undo my vote. Mea culpa.

Comment: Ah well, thank you for downvoting anyway.  Also it wasn't about what the version is doing or not but about updating the version, so there is that also.